# What is an N-frame image? Or an N-Frame?

Tags: framing

What is an N-frame image? Or an N-Frame?

I am reading Infinite Jest and there is a passage that reads:

"A Parody of neoconceptual structuralist films of Godbout and Vodriad, N-FRAME IMAGES of myriad varieties of small household flames, from lighters and birthday candles..."

Comment: While you might find someone here with the cinematography background to answer that, I suspect you'll have better luck asking this on a site having to do with cinematography/video, rather than one having to do with still photography...

Comment: At least provide links, we don't know about Infinite Jest and it's up to you to guide us.

Answer (score 4):

The quote describes short movie "Various Small Flames". Here is cover for it:
[image]

[source](http://pooryorickentertainment.tumblr.com/post/6097981730/design-by-chris-ayers-various-small)

I think that N-frame image is an image made up from N separate images. We use this language in physics, like 3-dimensional, meaning having 3 dimensions.

For example, this can be considered 18-frame image:

[image]

[Source](http://belindashi.com/free-giveaways/google-plus-cover-photo-collage-adobe-lightroom-template-free/)

Comment: I only see 17 distinct images in the second example marked '18-frame.'

Comment: I see 18. They alternate columns of 3 and 2. Do you see a column that doesn't fit that pattern?